How to Reduce Log Storage Volume on GCP (aka delete logs) when documented methods fail
I need to somehow reduce the cost of GCP Log Storage after excessive logging event.
gcloud logging logs list and then gcloud logging logs delete does not help, the logs are still accessible and the daily spent does not get smaller.
Decreasing the retention from default 30 days to minimum 1 does not help either, the logs are still accessible and the daily spent does not get smaller.
Everything is default: the the Logging API is just turned on, no special config, i.e. the sink with the _Default bucket, which can't be deleted and so on. The sources of the logs are mainly GKE Autopilot cluster.
The problematic thing is some deployment from the cluster which was scaled up 100x with debug-like logging on. Which ended up in projects/projectname/logs/stderr projects/projectname/logs/stdout if i delete them with gcloud logging logs delete nothing happens the command finishes ok, the logs are still accessible, the billing still accounts as if the logs are there. The spent rises every day. Bad. Do you please have some ideas I can try?
(There is one thing I'm considering that is turning the Logging API off and after some time on again, but I'm afraid of side effects)
Thanks
